# Parsing an xml response using NSXml

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I trying to parse an xml that has one root element with 2 child elements with the same name. However they keep getting concatenated together. How can i fix this? here is my code so far

-

```
(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    element = elementName;

    if([element isEqualToString:@"bustime-response"]){
        self.item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        self.direction =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"dir"]){
        string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        [self.direction appendString:string];
    }
}
```

Comment: I this [this link][1] may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15059421/2869784

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"bustime-response"])
    {
        elementFound = YES;

        if (self.item)
            self.item = nil;
        self.item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        if (self.direction)
            self.direction  = nil;
        self.direction =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFound)
    {
        if ([element isEqualToString:@"dir"]){
            string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            [self.direction appendString:string];
        }
        //Add another if with the tag you want to retrieve the data from here
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"bustime-response"])
    {
        elementFound = NO;
        // self.receivedDataArray - main array to store all of your dictionary
        [self.receivedDataArray addObject: self.direction];
            [self.receivedDataArray addObject: self.item];
        self.direction = nil;
            self.item = nil;
    }
}
```

As you see you have to add another BOOL variable elementFound and NSMutableArray receivedDataArray for storing all of the data. Give it a go and let me know is it work for you. Remember it's good to add NSLogs for debugging, it helps a lot.

Comment: I tried the above solution and it still did not work. I also tried an nslog and it appears that the value of the child element is assigned 5 times.

Comment: I don't know how your XML file looks like. This code above works fine for me, Try add NSLog in parser:foundCharacters: method inside if(elementFound) and if([element isEqualToString) - NSLog(@"found: %@", string)